# How to use groupby to find events within one year of current event for all IDs

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a large pandas dataframe with IDs and encounter dates:

```
ID     Encounter_date
A      2019-01-01 17:00
B      2019-01-01 17:00
A      2018-06-01 17:00
A      2017-01-01 17:00
```

I would like to capture the ID-wise encounters within 1 year *pd.Timedelta(days=365)* prior to the listed encounter date such that I arrive at an output df like:

```
ID     Encounter_date     within_1_year
A      2019-01-01 17:00   3
B      2019-01-01 17:00   1
A      2018-06-01 17:00   2
A      2018-01-02 17:00   2
A      2017-05-01 17:00   1
```

For example, for the first row, there are three encounters between 2018-01-01 and 2019-01-01, specifically: row 1, row 3, row 4. Row 2 is a different ID and row 5 is not within a year.

I found doing ID-wise computations by iterating through unique IDs and finding the associated rows to be slow and could not figure out how to do this with groupby.

Thanks for your consideration.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: How many rows does your dataframe have?

Comment: About a million rows with 250K unique IDs

Comment: What would you like to see from my code - just a way to make the dataframe above? I don't have even a slow solution to my problem coded out.